# Track event time for web application

Tags: google-analytics

I am implementing event tracking system in to my web application using Google Analytic. 
 using

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

but I cannot find a a way to track the event time as well for each events

any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are time-based dimensions in the custom reports, for instance Dimensions > Visitors > Hour.  Have you checked that out?

But if you were wanting to specifically pass the time...

What are you using "category", "action" and "opt_label" for?  I'm guessing you are probably using category and action, but are you using opt_label?  You can pass the current timestamp there...

Alternatively you could pass a [custom variable](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html) with a timestamp value. Depending on how much traffic you are getting, and/or expected length of activities...I would suggest rounding the times to nearest quarter hour, half hour, full hour, half day or full day or whatever (again, whatever makes most sense for your site).  That way you won't have to sort out hits for literally every second of the day (because really, how actionable is it to know 100 visitors did something at 12:00p vs. 12:01p, sort of thing)

Comment: Thanx how can i do this   "What are you using "category", "action" and "opt_label" for? I'm guessing you are probably using category and action, but are you using opt_label? You can pass the current timestamp there... " how can i use opt_lable to pass current time